# How to show a div behind other div with the scroll of the mouse

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

I'm trying to do an effect that hide a div behind other like this page: [Canalla Agency](https://canalla.agency/). I use two divs and the last one with position fixed, and it's worked, but the div lost the height.

Sorry for my explanation but I'm not good in CSS positioning and Javascript. I hope you can help me and see you soon. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @David Alejandro and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you add some more detail on what you already tried, so people helping you don't duplicate your effort! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with three `<div>`'s:

The only tricky bit is the "viewer" div creates the scrolling space to see the background div.

No JS required!

Also remember to specify `position` when using `z-index`.

```
<html>
    <style>
        #cover, #viewer, #background {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: relative;
            padding-top: 50vh;
            text-align: center;
            height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;                
        }
        #cover {
            background-color: paleturquoise;
            z-index: 1;
        }
        #viewer {
            z-index: -1;
        }
        #background {
            background-color: coral;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="cover">
            <h1>This Scrolls Up</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="viewer"></div>
        <div id="background">
            <h1>This Stays Static</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to answer... really thanks for the solution, it was really helpful.